# Changes to model taking effect in console but not at localhost:3000 (server restart required??)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, localhost

I'm writing validations for a model in my Rails 4 app and for some reason the changes aren't taking effect when I access the page at localhost:3000.

For example, I wrote several `presence: :true` validations for the Product model's price, description, and image_url attributes as well as a numericality validation for its price. When I make a new invalid object in the rails console it is correctly flagged as invalid. However, when I go to the page at localhost:3000/products and refresh I'm able to create a new object even with invalid attributes.

I did some searching on StackOverflow and found a few things about adding something to my config but I was under the impression that changes to models should take effect immediately in development and (though I'm a beginner) I don't remember ever having to change any configuration to make sure that was the case. And, as already noted, the changes *are* taking effect in the console, just not on the page itself.

Is this normal behavior?? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You're right that it should autoreload so long as your server really is running in the development environment and caching is off (in the config for development.rb). If you add a debugger and use the debug prompt to evaluate `Rails.application.config.cache_classes` what do you get? Should be `false`. Also check `Rails.application.config.action_controller.perform_caching`.

Comment: I'm pretty early on the in the Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book. Haven't used a debugger yet but I can look for a tutorial or something. I ran those commands in the Rails console and they both returned false. Also, Rails.env.development? is true

Comment: No idea what's going on here. Now I've made changes to a flash notice in a controller and THAT's not taking effect at localhost:3000 without restarting the server either.

Comment: Install the [pry gem](https://github.com/pry/pry) and put `binding.pry` somewhere in the action in your controller code. Restart the serve rand then run it. That should give you a breakpoint at that point in the code. Then you can use the server like a console and figure out what's going on there. Are you starting the server with `rails s` or `rails server`? (Either is fine). Or something else?

Comment: I am using `rails s` to start the server.

Comment: So I'm using a virtual machine through VirtualBox/Vagrant and in my frustration I decided to do a full closeout (`vagrant halt`) before opening a new terminal and reopening Vagrant. Also did a full system reboot. One or more of these steps seem to have fixed the problem. Any idea why restarting the VM would fix this problem, or what could have happened that these problems would start happening and rebooting the VM would fix it??

Comment: That's odd. But, no... I've never tried to develop with a VM so I've no experience to draw on there. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Are you using webwrick? If you are then just use gem thin